# discord py type a new command which only works after first one ist triggered

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a bot to play blackjack and i managed to get the bot to give out a card if you type $blackjack. Now i want that after you type $blackjack you can type $hit or $stand right now it works if you write the command like $blackjacks $hit in one message but that's useless since you don't know what you wanna do before you know your card.

This is my code:

```
        elif message.content.startswith("$blackjack"):
        blackjack_ziehe_karte()
        ansage_der_karte = (message.author.name + " "+ "du hast die karte/n: "+ karte)
        await message.channel.send(ansage_der_karte)


            if "$hit" in message.content:
                blackjack_ziehe_karte()
                ansage_der_karte = ansage_der_karte + " " + ", " + karte
                await message.channel.send(ansage_der_karte)

            elif "$stand"  in message.content:
                await message.channel.send ( "test")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to store all the active games somewhere. This would probably work fine in memory, but you may choose to use a database for persistence and sharing across multiple services/instances.

This storage below is `client.games` which is a dictionary where the keys are the user's Discord ID and the value is an instance of `Game`.

It is recommended to use `discord.ext.commands` instead of using `on_message`, especially with more complex commands. There is an [overview](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) on the docs which goes in-depth into why you might want to use it and how to get started.

For example:

```py
import discord

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit: str, value: str) -> None:
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

class Game:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cards: list[Card] = []

    def hit(self) -> Card:
        # Return a random `Card` instance
        raise NotImplementedError()

    ...

# Assuming you're not using `commands.Bot` and therefore not a `commands.Cog`
client = discord.Client(...)
client.games = {}  # user_id: `Game`

...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "$blackjack" == message.content:
        game = Game()
        card = game.hit()
        # e.g. Send card and show existing cards, handle going bust
        ...
        client.games[message.author.id] = game

    if "$hit" == message.content:
        # You can use .get() to avoid raising if they have not already started a game
        game = client.games[message.author.id]
        card = game.hit()
        # e.g. Send card and show existing cards, handle going bust
        ...

    if "$stand" == message.content:
        ...
        # Once the game is over, remove it
        client.games.pop(message.author.id)
```